# Redirect with query stings

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I have a very annoying redirect I cannot figure out.

I have many hundreds of page like the below:

```
example.com/directory/in.php?url_id=28930
```

I want to redirect all e.g. `/directory/in.php?url_id=28930`

The redirects will all go to the homepage.

What redirect rule could you suggest?

I have already attempted many redirect rules but all fail for some reason.

Comment: "I have already attempted many" - it would be good to show what you have tried (at least your best attempt), as it might just be a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To check for specific query strings you need to use mod_rewrite and a `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. (The `RewriteRule` pattern only matches against the URL-path, which notably excludes the query string.)

For example, to redirect the specific URL `/directory/in.php?url_id=28930` in the root `.htaccess` file, you would do something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url_id=28930$
RewriteRule ^directory/in\.php$ / [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The `QSD` flag (Query String Discard - Apache 2.4+ only) removes the query string from the redirected URL. If you are on Apache 2.2 then you will need to append a `?` to the end of the *substitution* string instead, ie. `/?`, in order to effectively remove the query string from the redirected URL. Otherwise, by default, the query string from the request is passed through to the target URL (ie. *susbstitution* argument).

Note also, this is a temporary 302 redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then change the `302` to `301` only when you are sure it's working OK (to avoid any caching issues).

To make this more general and redirect any URL that contains a numeric `url_id` parameter value, then change the `RewriteCond` directive to something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url_id=\d+$
```

*Aside:* From an SEO point of view, mass redirects like this to the homepage are likely to be seen as soft-404s by Google and other search engines.

Comment: For the one for Apache 2.2, would this be:  RewriteRule ^directory/in\.php$ /? [QSD,R=302,L] -- when I put your above one in I get domain.com/?url_id=28930  so the url_id is retained although it does redirect to the homepage.  I also get what you mean about this being seen as a soft 404 but better to have it in place than not I feel!

Comment: Almost - you need to remove the `QSD` flag if you are on Apache 2.2. ie. `RewriteRule ^directory/in\.php$ /? [R=302,L]`. Make sure you clear your browser cache. The `?` on the end of the _substitution_ OR the `QSD` flag specifically removes the `?url_id=28930` (query string) part, so if you are still seeing the query string on the redirected URL then either you are seeing a cached response or _something else_ is redirecting it.

Comment: How did you get on with this? If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted (click the checkmark on the left, below the voting arrows) to remove it from the unanswered question queue. Once you have 15+ rep you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)